# File.Exists issue with UNC shared folder

Tags: .net

we have recently upgrade an asp.net 2.0 project to .net 4.0 on windows 2008 r2 server, one of the issue we found is the File.Exists() call to the UNC shared folder. it was working fine with the .net 2 on windows 2003 server. what the code does is using windows impersonation to access the shared folder for a file that is created by a web service. it seems like File.Exists() returns false even if the file exists on the shared folder just created by the web service. now I think the File object from the web service might not be closed at the time when the local code try to access the file. so how to fix this issue with the .net 4 implementation of the File.Exists method, I try setting the thread to sleep for a few seconds but no help and it's not a good solution anyway.

any ideas?

Update:

OK, so I add a while loop to wait for the file to be closed by the web service. now File.Exits return true during the while loop. it's interesting that it works fine in asp.net 2.0. not sure if .net 4 has different implementation or the server difference cause this different behavior.

Comment: Show us some code. But it really sounds like a permissions issue. You might consider trying to list the files in that directory or open a file on that share. I suspect you'll end up with an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Comment: no, I try to check for other files that are already sitting that in folder, it works fine. so that leads me to believe that the File object is not closed (which is not likely since the exact same code works fine with asp.net 2.0 on windows 2003 server) or some network latency for refreshing the file status issue.

Comment: OK, so I add a while loop to wait for the file to be closed by the web service. now File.Exits return true during the while loop. it's interesting that it works fine in asp.net 2.0. not sure if .net 4 has different implementation or the server difference cause this different behavior.

Comment: So the problem is that the Web service isn't closing the file in a timely manner? Is there perhaps a bug in the way the file is written? Failing to call `Close`, or `Dispose`?

Comment: I put a while loop to wait to check the file, it returns true after about 4.5 seconds. the thing is it works fine for asp.net 2.0. now I start to wonder if asp.net 4 has some kind async woodoo going on. but I know the page mode is not set to async.